# how to serialize JSON object lists into file with c# not array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this code right here to add a piece of JSON to a file, but instead of working it makes an array with [] breaking how my file is read.

```cs
var serverid = ctx.Guild.Id.ToString();
List<data> _data = new List<data>();
_data.Add(new data() {
    mute = $"{Role.Name}"
});
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data.ToList());
File.WriteAllText(@$".\serverconfigs\{serverid}.json", json);
```

Comment: ```[{"mute":"CobraMute"}]``` is what i mean

Comment: So why did you serialize a list then? Just serialize the `data` object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your JSON without square brackets, simply omit the list when you serialize:

```
var _data = new data() {
    mute = $"{Role.Name}"
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data);
File.WriteAllText(@$".\serverconfigs\{serverid}.json", json);
```

This will generate: `{"mute" : "CobraMute"}` assumuing that `Role.Name` is `CobraMute`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid json. You would need to create a class with an array. Then when you serialize that class it would be serialized like this :

> {"_data":[{"mute":"CobraMute"}]}

In your code, it would be like this :

```
class Program
{
    YourClass myclass = new YourClass();
    myclass._data = new List<data>();
    myclass._data.Add(new data()
    {
        mute = $"{Role.Name}"
    });
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myclass);
    File.WriteAllText(@$".\serverconfigs\{serverid}.json", json);
}
class YourClass{
    public List<data> _data;
}
```

Comment: should of clarified [{"mute":"CobraMute"}] is what was returned when the file was generated but i just want ```{"mute" : "CobraMute"}```

Comment: So don't serialize the list, just serialize the object itself.

Comment: Then just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data[0])` instead.